# What is the stance of the LDS Church on gender?

Tags: lds, gender

Gender is a hot topic as of late, with a seemingly small but very vocal minority preaching that gender is fluid, non-binary, and that people may choose to identify with whatever gender they wish.

What is the official stance of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints on the matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints has a very clear stance on the topic of gender.

> 27 So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he
>   him; male and female created he them. [(Gen 1:27)](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/gen/1.27?lang=eng&clang=eng#p26)

There are only **two genders: MALE and FEMALE**, every spirit child of our Father in Heaven (every human being ever born on Earth) is *one* of these genders, has been one of these genders since before the creation of the Earth, and will remain the same gender for all of eternity.

> ALL HUMAN BEINGS—male and female—are created in the image of God. Each
>   is a beloved spirit son or daughter of heavenly parents, and, as such,
>   each has a divine nature and destiny. **Gender is an essential
>   characteristic of individual premortal, mortal, and eternal identity
>   and purpose.** [*(The Family: A proclomation to the World)*](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/the-family-a-proclamation-to-the-world/the-family-a-proclamation-to-the-world?lang=eng)

This stance was recently reaffirmed at the October 2018 General Conference of the Church:

> ...some are troubled by some of our Church’s positions on marriage and
>   children. Our knowledge of God’s revealed plan of salvation requires
>   us to oppose current social and legal pressures to retreat from
>   traditional marriage and to make changes that confuse or alter gender
>   or homogenize the differences between men and women. We know that the
>   relationships, identities, and functions of men and women are
>   essential to accomplish God’s great plan. [*(Truth and the Plan. 2018)*](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2018/10/truth-and-the-plan?lang=eng)

Gender is eternal and unchangeable. When our spirits were created an eternity ago, before the very foundations of the universe were formed, we were created as either male, or female, and we will remain the same gender throughout all time and eternity.

Answer (score 6):

The recent revision of the General Handbook of Instructions (as of 19 Feb 2020) affirms that the discussion of gender in the Proclamation on the Family refers to biological sex at birth and considers it immutable. In particular, eligibility for Priesthood ordination or  temple ordinances is determined by this.  Attempts to transition to the other sex medically, socially, or behaviorally are discouraged and members who do so may face restrictions on their membership.  Hormone therapy by established medical professionals for treatment of gender dysphoria or suicidal tendencies may be permitted, provided that this is not part of an attempt to transition to the other sex.

For those rare cases in which the biological sex at birth is not clear, questions should be referred by local leaders to the First Presidency.